# how url_for can check constraints from my routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I try define some translate routes on my rails application. The route change with the subdomain define. So I want this result :

```
  describe "url_for" do
    context 'with en' do
      it 'brand translate' do
        url_for(
          :controller => 'boats',
          :action => 'index',
          :subdomain => :en,
          :brand => 'hello',                                                                                                                                                         
          :only_path => true
        ).should == '/yacht-charter/brand-hello'
      end
    end

    context 'with fr' do
      it 'brand translate' do
        url_for(
          :controller => 'boats',
          :action => 'index',
          :subdomain => :fr,
          :brand => 'hello',
          :only_path => true
        ).should == '/location-bateau/marque-hello'
      end 
    end   
  end
```

Like you can see the only change between both url_for params is the subdomain. I try :

```
  constraints => :subdomain => :en  do                                                                                                                   
    match '/yacht-charter/brand-:brand' => 'boats#index', :as => 'en_brand_search'
  end 

  constraints :subdomain => :fr do
    match '/location-bateau/marque-:brand' => 'boats#index', :as => 'fr_brand_search'
  end
```

But all the time it's the first route define it use. the second is never define.

How Can i do that. It's a rails bug or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about it being a rails bug or not, but have a look at https://github.com/francesc/rails-translate-routes it works well and may help achieving this.

Comment: I have already test this gem and it's works fine, but not works with url like `'/yacht-charter/brand-:brand` works only with url like `'/yacht-charter/brand/:brand`